# javascript confirm box before leaving inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use confirm() box to check whether users want to exit the current page or not when they click cancle.
My goal is if the user clicks yes, then it will go to the previous page, if the user clicks no, then it will stay in the current page.

Inside the html file, the input field has onclick function like below.

```
<input action="action" id="cancle" onclick="return DeleteFunction()" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
```

And inside the script field, I implemented the function like below:

```
function DeleteFunction(){
    var result = confirm("Really leaving?");
    if(result){
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, when I click yes, then it goes to the page where it submits the form, which means window.history.go(-1) does not work.
Is there any possible ways to make it work as I desired?

Comment: Can you share a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your example works fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **window.history.back();** if it is not working but it works there is no issue with the line. However, you do not need else condition here, please remove it. Try this piece of code:

```
    let res = confirm("Really leaving?");
    console.log(res);    
    if(res){
        // window.history.back();
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
```